# Filter data from 1000+ csv files matching consecutive row data

Tags: powershell, csv

On Windows so may be a Powershell solution?

I have 1000+ csv files in a folder I want to check and get data from.

I've simplified the csv for the purpose of this post, it has 3 columns - row, time and RecvBytes

```
row,time,RecvByts
1,19/Mar/2024:02:50:17 ,3614
2,19/Mar/2024:02:50:18 ,3614
3,19/Mar/2024:02:50:20 ,4256
4,19/Mar/2024:02:50:20 ,166293
5,19/Mar/2024:02:50:20 ,166293
6,19/Mar/2024:02:50:20 ,166293
7,19/Mar/2024:02:50:21 ,161693
8,19/Mar/2024:02:50:21 ,177112
9,19/Mar/2024:02:50:21 ,146236
10,19/Mar/2024:02:50:21 ,146236
```

I need to keep rows that have consecutive matching values in column RecvByts - I would write these rows to a new file to keep things straight forward.

```
In the sample above rows 1,2,4,5,6,9,10 would be kept because 

row 2.RecvByts = row 1.RecvByts - keep both these rows
row 5.RecvByts = row 4.RecvByts - keep both these rows
row 6.RecvByts = row 5.RecvByts - keep both these rows
row 10.RecvByts = row 9.RecvByts - keep both these rows
```

So the output would look like this:

```
row,time,RecvByts
1,19/Mar/2024:02:50:17 ,3614
2,19/Mar/2024:02:50:18 ,3614
4,19/Mar/2024:02:50:20 ,166293
5,19/Mar/2024:02:50:20 ,166293
6,19/Mar/2024:02:50:20 ,166293
9,19/Mar/2024:02:50:21 ,146236
10,19/Mar/2024:02:50:21 ,146236
```

First part I've tried but failed is to compare consecutive rows:

```
$fileIn = import-csv C:\123.csv
$fileOut = @()

foreach($a in $fileIn) {
    if($a.RecvByts -eq $fileOut[+1].RecvByts) {
    $fileOut += $a
     }
 }

$fileOut
```

Thanks

D/

Comment: Please, [DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557), see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Your question as it stands is likely to attract votes to close. This site works best when you ask questions about code *you've already written* - it's not really a free code writing service. If you've already written something and need help with it you should post the relevant section in a "Minimal Reproducible Example" - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for more info.

Comment: What have you tried and what results have you got?

Comment: I would use Group-Object : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.4

Comment: @ iRon - it was the editor that asked to insert my rows of text as an image is I respond positively to the question. @ mclayton @sirtao - I started with this to compare rows and they are not matching what I'm looking for - so trying to solve this first before getting to looping through all files and outputting: $fileIn = import-csv C:\123.csv
$fileOut = @()

foreach($a in $fileIn) {
    if($a.ColumnC -eq $fileOut[+1].ColumnC) {
        $filOout += $a
    }
}

$fileOut

Comment: Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-asks). I think you should take your own question/issue more serious, otherwise you will probably never resolve this. E.g. there is typo in your example which will obviously never work.

Comment: sort-object -unique ?

Comment: Why would you end up with _2 with 1612 then 3 with 1612_ and not simply 5 with 1612? Are there other criteria you make no mention of? In the case of _1612_, all rows look the same in your picture. Also, what is your intent? Remove rows from csv files and then?? Overwrite the originals? Save the new data somewhere else or ??

Comment: @iron - typos are easily done - your 'How to ask' link has one - should be https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask not https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-asks

Comment: @Theo - I would just be keeping them in time order as they happened - yes the 2 and 3 groups would just form a 5 group

Comment: @DonaldMartin Please copy and post a raw CSV sample (eg. `Get-Content C:\123.csv |Select -First 10 |Set-Clipboard`) if you want the question reopened

Comment: The question is improved. Voting to reopen.

Comment: You want to keep SPECIFICALLY consecutive rows with the same RecvBytes value? Or just remove any row with a unique RecvBytes value?

Comment: @sirtao yes that's correct  "You want to keep SPECIFICALLY consecutive rows with the same RecvBytes value"

Comment: Does that mean that is a RecvByts value of 166293 appears later as a record without a following match to 166293 that it would be discarded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to making this work is to remember the previous record.
This is done in the `$PreviousRecord` variable.
`$GotMatch` is used to indicate if there has been a previous match.

```
#function Get-FilteredCsvFile {
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [string] $CsvIn = './so78193180.csv'
)

begin {
    $Records = Import-Csv -Path $CsvIn
    $PreviousRecord = $null
    $GotMatch = $false
}

process {
    foreach ($Record in $Records) {
        if ($PreviousRecord.RecvByts -eq $Record.RecvByts) {
            $PreviousRecord
            $GotMatch = $true
        } else {
            if ($GotMatch) {
                $PreviousRecord
                $GotMatch = $false
            }
        }
        $PreviousRecord = $Record
    }
}

end {
    if ($GotMatch) { $PreviousRecord }
}
#}
```

An example run based on the data in the question.

```
PS C:\src\t> .\so78193180.ps1

row time                  RecvByts
--- ----                  --------
1   19/Mar/2024:02:50:17  3614
2   19/Mar/2024:02:50:18  3614
4   19/Mar/2024:02:50:20  166293
5   19/Mar/2024:02:50:20  166293
6   19/Mar/2024:02:50:20  166293
9   19/Mar/2024:02:50:21  146236
10  19/Mar/2024:02:50:21  146236
```

Comment: thank for this, initial test look like it works well. I need to do some further testing and tweak the script to suit my needs but I couldn't have asked for more than this. I'll post back next week with a full breakdown of what I find. Thanks again